# What is the best way to compare time periods and how do I structure my database for it?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a way, that if my app says "Looking for person available from **March 3rd, 2016 8:00 am to March 3rd, 2016 3:00 pm**" to match it with a person that might be available from **March 3rd, 2016 7:00 am to March 3rd, 2016 16:00 pm.**

Now this is a just a snapshot, it has to scale for infinite times/dates for example a person might be available from **March 3rd, 2016 7:00 am to 9:00 am, then again from 2:00pm to 8:00pm**, so I'd have to have a way to filter people like this as a not complete match.

What I have so far is ONE TABLE that holds the dates to match against, so for example March 3rd 8 - 3pm, March 4th 8 - 3pm, March 5th 8 - 3pm..etc..

Another table that holds people and their availability as child elements, but I am not sure how to structure this part to make it easy and efficient to match inside loops with the other table.

Right now, in my employee table I have one field "March 3rd" and then another field with hours/minutes available as an array so for example "8:00, 8:15, 8:30, 8:45, 9:00...etc... The hours increments have to be in 15 min periods, so I can't just put 8am - 5pm for example...especially if the person is available during certain periods of the day...

Here is what my "employee select your availability looks like"

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover employe-availability-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="warning"> Hour </th>
        <th class="warning"> 15 </th>
        <th class="warning"> 30 </th>
        <th class="warning"> 45 </th>
        <th class="warning"> Hour </th>
        <th class="warning"> 15 </th>
        <th class="warning"> 30 </th>
        <th class="warning"> 45 </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td data-hour="0" data-minute="00" data-day-period="N" class="hour"> 0:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="0:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="0" data-minute="15" data-day-period="N"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="0:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="0" data-minute="30" data-day-period="N"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="0:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="0" data-minute="45" data-day-period="N"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="0:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour="12" data-minute="00" data-day-period="J" class="hour"> 12:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="12:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="12" data-minute="15" data-day-period="J"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="12:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="12" data-minute="30" data-day-period="J"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="12:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="12" data-minute="45" data-day-period="J"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="12:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-hour="1" data-minute="00" data-day-period="N" class="hour"> 1:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="1:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="1" data-minute="15" data-day-period="N"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="1:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="1" data-minute="30" data-day-period="N"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="1:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="1" data-minute="45" data-day-period="N"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="1:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour="13" data-minute="00" data-day-period="J" class="hour"> 13:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="13:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="13" data-minute="15" data-day-period="J"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="13:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="13" data-minute="30" data-day-period="J"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="13:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="13" data-minute="45" data-day-period="J"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="13:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-hour="2" data-minute="00" data-day-period="N" class="hour"> 2:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="2:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="2" data-minute="15" data-day-period="N"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="2:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="2" data-minute="30" data-day-period="N"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="2:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="2" data-minute="45" data-day-period="N"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="2:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour="14" data-minute="00" data-day-period="J" class="hour"> 14:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="14:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="14" data-minute="15" data-day-period="J"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="14:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="14" data-minute="30" data-day-period="J"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="14:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="14" data-minute="45" data-day-period="J"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="14:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-hour="3" data-minute="00" data-day-period="N" class="hour"> 3:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="3:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="3" data-minute="15" data-day-period="N"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="3:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="3" data-minute="30" data-day-period="N"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="3:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="3" data-minute="45" data-day-period="N"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="3:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour="15" data-minute="00" data-day-period="S" class="hour"> 15:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="15:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="15" data-minute="15" data-day-period="S"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="15:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="15" data-minute="30" data-day-period="S"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="15:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="15" data-minute="45" data-day-period="S"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="15:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-hour="4" data-minute="00" data-day-period="N" class="hour"> 4:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="4:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="4" data-minute="15" data-day-period="N"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="4:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="4" data-minute="30" data-day-period="N"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="4:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="4" data-minute="45" data-day-period="N"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="4:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour="16" data-minute="00" data-day-period="S" class="hour"> 16:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="16:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="16" data-minute="15" data-day-period="S"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="16:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="16" data-minute="30" data-day-period="S"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="16:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="16" data-minute="45" data-day-period="S"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="16:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-hour="5" data-minute="00" data-day-period="N" class="hour"> 5:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="5:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="5" data-minute="15" data-day-period="N"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="5:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="5" data-minute="30" data-day-period="N"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="5:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="5" data-minute="45" data-day-period="N"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="5:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour="17" data-minute="00" data-day-period="S" class="hour"> 17:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="17:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="17" data-minute="15" data-day-period="S"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="17:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="17" data-minute="30" data-day-period="S"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="17:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="17" data-minute="45" data-day-period="S"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="17:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-hour="6" data-minute="00" data-day-period="N" class="hour"> 6:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="6:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="6" data-minute="15" data-day-period="N"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="6:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="6" data-minute="30" data-day-period="N"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="6:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="6" data-minute="45" data-day-period="N"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="6:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour="18" data-minute="00" data-day-period="S" class="hour"> 18:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="18:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="18" data-minute="15" data-day-period="S"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="18:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="18" data-minute="30" data-day-period="S"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="18:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="18" data-minute="45" data-day-period="S"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="18:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-hour="7" data-minute="00" data-day-period="J" class="hour"> 7:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="7:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="7" data-minute="15" data-day-period="J"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="7:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="7" data-minute="30" data-day-period="J"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="7:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="7" data-minute="45" data-day-period="J"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="7:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour="19" data-minute="00" data-day-period="S" class="hour"> 19:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="19:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="19" data-minute="15" data-day-period="S"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="19:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="19" data-minute="30" data-day-period="S"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="19:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="19" data-minute="45" data-day-period="S"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="19:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-hour="8" data-minute="00" data-day-period="J" class="hour"> 8:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="8:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="8" data-minute="15" data-day-period="J"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="8:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="8" data-minute="30" data-day-period="J"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="8:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="8" data-minute="45" data-day-period="J"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="8:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour="20" data-minute="00" data-day-period="S" class="hour"> 20:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="20:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="20" data-minute="15" data-day-period="S"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="20:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="20" data-minute="30" data-day-period="S"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="20:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="20" data-minute="45" data-day-period="S"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="20:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-hour="9" data-minute="00" data-day-period="J" class="hour"> 9:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="9:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="9" data-minute="15" data-day-period="J"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="9:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="9" data-minute="30" data-day-period="J"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="9:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="9" data-minute="45" data-day-period="J"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="9:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour="21" data-minute="00" data-day-period="S" class="hour"> 21:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="21:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="21" data-minute="15" data-day-period="S"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="21:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="21" data-minute="30" data-day-period="S"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="21:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="21" data-minute="45" data-day-period="S"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="21:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-hour="10" data-minute="00" data-day-period="J" class="hour"> 10:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="10:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="10" data-minute="15" data-day-period="J"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="10:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="10" data-minute="30" data-day-period="J"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="10:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="10" data-minute="45" data-day-period="J"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="10:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour="22" data-minute="00" data-day-period="S" class="hour"> 22:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="22:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="22" data-minute="15" data-day-period="S"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="22:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="22" data-minute="30" data-day-period="S"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="22:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="22" data-minute="45" data-day-period="S"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="22:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-hour="11" data-minute="00" data-day-period="J" class="hour"> 11:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="11:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="11" data-minute="15" data-day-period="J"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="11:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="11" data-minute="30" data-day-period="J"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="11:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="11" data-minute="45" data-day-period="J"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="11:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour="23" data-minute="00" data-day-period="N" class="hour"> 23:00 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="23:00" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="23" data-minute="15" data-day-period="N"> 15 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="23:15" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="23" data-minute="30" data-day-period="N"> 30 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="23:30" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
        <td data-hour-ref="23" data-minute="45" data-day-period="N"> 45 <input type="checkbox" class="hide undoUniform" name="field_108890_tab_14" value="23:45" style="display: inline-block;"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any nudge in the right direction regarding my logic and setup would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a first thought, I would strongly suggest that you use Mysql's `DATETIME` type for each "availability" rather than storing fragments of your timestamps in separate fields. That will make everything a lot easier.

Comment: Is this data coming from a database? If so the solution probably lies in an SQL query...

Comment: why do you have so much duplication? `data-hour/minute` etc.. when you have that info as an input value **and** as the html text. The same information in 4 separate places...on the same line, very bloated code. Plus in-line styles. You're already have classes - use them.

Comment: @Adrenaxus how exactly do you suggest I store multiple time periods, in one time stamp? It's not a simple problem of from 8am - 4pm.. that is easy in START TIME STAMP  - END TIMESTAMP...but if you have multiple blocks like 8am - 10am then again 4pm-8pm... that is where my problem is...

Comment: @Amir: You don't store multiple time periods in ONE timestamp. You could rather store every time period as an entry with `start` and `end` datetimes in your `availabilities` table. So for example Tom is available from `2015-03-28 14:00:00` to `2015-03-28 16:00:00` and from `2015-04-28 14:00:00` to `2015-04-28 17:00:00` etc. It's basically what Pigeon proposed in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did a quick ideone for it [here](https://ideone.com/T3fEgN) SQLFiddle always messes up for me.

Whether this is the best solution or not, time will tell; but I do believe it is *a* solution to your problem.

We have your `Employee` Table, and we also have an `Availability` Table

The `Availability` table will contain a `start` and an `end` and anything in between those two values will be considered the `duration` / `available time`

(I don't have time right now to make fancy class diagrams and such I'm afraid, so you'll have to deal with text :p!)

To clarify the tables:

> **Employee**
>   @id
>   name
>   ...
>
> **Availability**
>   @id
>   start
>   end
>   user_id

If you filled these in with values such as:

```
INSERT INTO Employee
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Mike');

INSERT INTO Availability
  (`id`, `start`, `end`, `user_id`)
VALUES
  (1, '2016-01-01 12:00:00', '2016-01-01 17:00:00', 1),
  (2, '2016-01-01 14:00:00', '2016-01-01 19:00:00', 1);
```

Then we could use the following query to get all available entries that are available at a certain time:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Availability
WHERE '2016-01-01 18:00:00' AND '2016-01-01 18:30:00'
BETWEEN start AND end;
```

The above yields:
`2 | 2016-01-01 14:00:00 | 2016-01-01 19:00:00 | 1`

If you then wanted to get the Employee, you could `LEFT JOIN` based on the `user_id` to get the rest of the details you want.

I *believe* that should solve your requirement. Any issues let me know.

**Edit:**
Not sure what your requirement is afterwards, but just as a slight added part:

If you pull it out from the database, I would suggest you use PHP's `DateTime` library for parsing it.

`$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['start']);`

Then when you present the dates back to the user you can make it human readable:

`$date->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');`

Comment: I've had something like this before, and it works fine if the person is available in one chunk on one date. But in my case, I have people in multiple chunks of hours during the date. So for example 8am-10am... then again 3pm-8pm that same day...

Comment: The example should handle that, if you changed the `SELECT` to be between `2016-01-01 15:00:00` and `2016-01-01 15:30:00` it would pull out both the dates, which are two dates/chunks in the same day? So unless i'm misinterpreting your meaning, it should work. You have a new record for each chunk, so the fact you have multiple instances on the same day won't matter.